# Can I get contact information from a user's friend on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to write an application that fetches a list of a user's friends on Facebook, then creates contacts from the info it finds on them. Is there any way to access the friend's address, phone number, etc, or is that intentionally hidden? When I post to the graph api, it returns the name, work history, school history, birthday, etc. but no useful "contact" info.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fetch email of a friend in facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189245/fetch-email-of-a-friend-in-facebook-app)

Darn :-/